# How to limit total hits in elastic search during index creation

Tags: elasticsearch

My elastic index hitting these many results for any query, how can i limit the hits to 30 for any query.

```
{
    "took": 216,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 32974167,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
```

I should get output like this.

```
"hits": {
    "total": 29,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
        {
```

Comment: "total" is the number of documents that matches the query. Why there is a need to limit that?

Comment: Also elastic search by default returns only top 10 hits which also can be controlled by `from` and `size` param in query.

Comment: Why you want "total" as 29 instead of matching documents?

Comment: It was a mistake i was sending the query as q=* to elastic end point. Due to * it was giving all results irrespective of query. Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent > 30 hits, ensure you have a maximum of 30 documents in your index. If you want to restrict the number of documents returned, use the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) parameter.